# Как поучить кадры из видео на android?

Tags: android, видео

Делаю так

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
File file1 = new File(directory, "vrem.mp4");
retriever.setDataSource(file1.toString());
for (long i = 0; i < millis; i += 1000/fps) { //millis - длина видео в милисикундах
    Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i*1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
}
```

достает кадр только каждую 1 секунду, а нужно чаще, например 25 кадров в секунду, естественно если позволяет битрейд.

Answer (score 1):

В цикле шаг приращения равен длительности фрейма (кадра), но считывание картинки берётся через 1 секунду. Сделай множитель такой-же длительности:

```
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i*1000/fps, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```